# CSS grid layout: force fixed layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I made the following grid layout (for an upcoming email client):

```css
body
{
  margin:0px;
  font-family:tahoma;
  font-size:12px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "mailboxes messages messages"
    "mailboxes viewer viewer"
    "footer footer footer";

  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px;
  grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 70% 34px;
  grid-gap: 0px;

  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background:#aaa;
}

.mailboxes
{
  grid-area: mailboxes;
  background:#ccc;
}

.footer
{
  grid-area: footer;
  background:#aaa;
}

.gMessages
{
  grid-area: messages;
  background:#bbb;
}

.viewer
{
  grid-area: viewer;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="mailboxes">mailboxes</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>

        <div class="gMessages">
          messages
        </div>

        <div class="viewer">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also see here: https://jsfiddle.net/w4m1psnh/4/

It is responsive and everything is fine.
The problem is - when filling data into the messages Area (`.gMessages`), the area will enlarge and destroy my layout:

[image]

It also enlargens the page so that the footer will become invisible.
I couldn't find out how to keep the area in its fixed height and also keeping the whole layout responsive (messages: 30% height, viewer 70% height). 
I also tried assigning a fixed height and applying overlay-y to the Message content - without success. So how would i force the grid layout to keep its assigned dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 declarations for the same property here:

```
grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px;
grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 70% 34px;
```

The first one will be ignored. So assuming you want the top section to be 30%, keep second one.

Now we need to fix the overflow issue.

Add `overflow-y: auto` to `.viewer` and `.gMessages`

You will end up with this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>TITLE</title>
<style>
    body
    {
      margin:0px;
      font-family:tahoma;
      font-size:12px;
    }

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;

      grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "mailboxes messages messages"
        "mailboxes viewer viewer"
        "footer footer footer";

      grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px;
      grid-gap: 0px;

      height: 100vh;
    }

    .header {
      grid-area: header;
      background:#aaa;
    }

    .mailboxes
    {
      grid-area: mailboxes;
      background:#ccc;
    }

    .footer
    {
      grid-area: footer;
      background:#aaa;
    }

    .gMessages
    {
      grid-area: messages;
      background:#bbb;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .viewer
    {
      overflow-y: auto;
      grid-area: viewer;
      background:white;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="mailboxes">mailboxes</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>

        <div class="gMessages">
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
          messages<br/>
        </div>

        <div class="viewer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining `grid-template-rows` two times?

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px;
  grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 70% 34px;
}
```

There's no need for that. The browser (during the cascade) simply invalidates the first rule and uses the second one. In other words, the first rule is ignored.

[image]

Pick one or the other, or just use `auto` (content-based height).

Add this to your code:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px; */
  grid-template-rows: 34px auto 1fr 34px; /* adjustment */
}

.gMessages {
  grid-area: messages;
  overflow: auto;  /* new */
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "mailboxes messages messages"
    "mailboxes viewer viewer"
    "footer footer footer";
  
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  /* grid-template-rows: 34px 1fr 30% 34px; */
  grid-template-rows: 34px auto 1fr 34px; /* adjustment */
  height: 100vh;
}

.gMessages {
  grid-area: messages;
  background: #bbb;
  overflow: auto;  /* new */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #aaa;
}

.mailboxes {
  grid-area: mailboxes;
  background: #ccc;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #aaa;
}

.viewer {
  grid-area: viewer;
  background: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="mailboxes">mailboxes</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
  <div class="gMessages">text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text<br><br>text
    <div class="viewer"></div>
  </div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zeyw8r4u/)